# remove everything after a certain character vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to programming. I'm learning about visual basic at my school.

Is it possible to remove everything after a certain character in vb basic?

What I wanted to do is: remove everything in bold letter

**Text**

```
background-image: url("url =** example.com %2A%7Ehmac%3D0da31302030394a84ae567e54f5cce15b3e18133&_nc_hash=AQCFmBtOnL2EgdP6**
```

In my program, I let my user input a line of text in a text box, the line will be similar to **Text**.  And I can't think of how to remove
the unnecessary part after a certain character.

Here's my code, I have 2 textboxes, user will put the text in textbox1 and the result will be in textbox2.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   "i need code here"
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack overflow is not a free coding service. Instead of "i need code here" perhaps you could say what you've tried. There are lots of examples of string manipulation (which is what you're trying to do) in Visual Basic on the web. Try a Google search and if you've got a specific question then Stack Overflow can help.

Comment: Look up substring and IndexOf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can work with substing ( splits a string from & to a given index / position ) and the index of function ( get the index / position of a given character ) . 
You code then should look like this :

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
     Use this string literal for the demonstration.
    Dim literal As String = "CatDogFence"
    Dim pos as Integer

    ' Gives you the position of the D ( from DOG ) 
    ' - 1 because we dont want to see the D of dog

    pos = literal.IndexOf("D") -1

    ' Take the first three characters into a new string.
    ' ... Use the Substring method.

    Dim substring As String = literal.Substring(0, pos )

    ' substring will contain Cat , because we get from the substring 
    'everything from position 0 ( the start ) to 3 ( the D of Dog )
    ' Write the results to the screen.

    Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", substring)
End Sub
```

End Module